# HTML and CSS Fluid Circle

Tags: html, css, geometry, css-shapes

I am trying to create a fluid circle using HTML and CSS. I am almost done but as it should be fluid and content inside is dynamic, it's changing its shape from circle to oval and others.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
.notify {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 20%;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.notify > div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="notify">
  <div>
    12
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Make sure you test it changing text inside the div from 12 to 100 and etc

Comment: I've seen many answers suggesting the use of JavaScript in order to enforce a square aspect ratio of the element for a 50% border radius. I recently wrote a blog post on how this can be done solely with CSS: http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio

Comment: Oh, and Safari does not yet gracefully handle a border radius specified as a percentage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `border-radius:50%` hack which you're using makes the assumption that the `<div>` is square prior to the rounded corners being applied, otherwise it will produce an oval rather than a circle, exactly as you've noted.

Therefore, if you want the circle to remain circular as the content expands, you need to dynamically adjust the height to match the width. You'd probably need to use Javascript to achieve this.

Also, please note that `border-radius` is not supported in older versions of IE, so users with IE6, IE7 or IE8 won't see your circle at all. (though there is a hack for it called [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/))

Of course, adjusting the `height` will have the side effect of making the element take up more space vertically. This may not be what you want; you may want the the circle to be the same size regardless of what content is in it? In this case, you should fix the height and width of the circle, and give the content `position:absolute;` to prevent it from affecting the size of its parent.

An alternative to using the `border-radius` hack to produce a circle would be to use SVG. SVG is a vector graphics format which is embedded into most browsers.

Again, the notable exception is IE8 and earlier, but IE supports an alternative format called VML. Various scripts exist which can convert between SVG and VML, so you can produce a cross-browser solution with SVG plus Javascript.

If we're going to accept the Javascript is part of the solution, you could simply use a javascript library to draw it in the first place. My suggestion for this would be [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), which generates SVG or VML graphics according to the browser it's running it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set both `width` and `height` to the maximum of these both, in order to render a square, that with 50% radius corners, results into a circle.

You can do this in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var $elem = $(".notify > div");
  var maxSize = Math.max($elem.width(), $elem.height());

  $elem.width(maxSize).height(maxSize);
});
```

Try to change content (both in width and height) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2j5Ek/40/)

Answer (score 2):

[Example of a fluid circle](http://jsfiddle.net/ansciath/RtbXD/1/) using only HTML and CSS. As mentioned in my comments to the question, the technique is explained in my [blog post](http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio). Also as mentioned, Safari does not currently play nice with a border radius specified as a percentage.

Comment: It is interesting hack, but how to place content in the inner div now if I don't want to calculate absolute position for the content ?

Comment: The content (in this case, the circle) is absolutely positioned inside the container. The circle should occupy the full area of the container. In this way, the container acts as a kind of proxy for the content. The container can then be placed in any way that you want, calculating its position in any way that you want.

Answer (score 1):

The way as `Jose Rui Santos` did you can achieve your goal. But do few changes in your css.

Like remove padding from `.notify > div` and adding styles like this:

```
.notify > div
{    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and add padding into `.notify` class like this:

```
.notify
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 20%;
    background: red;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;

}
```

and Jquery code as mentioned by `Jose Rui Santos`:

```
var $elem = $(".notify > div");
var maxSize = Math.max($elem.width(), $elem.height());
$elem.width(maxSize).height(maxSize);
```

See the working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2j5Ek/63/

Answer (score 0):

you need a way to enforce height / width otherwise it will just go oval... its possible!

on this html

```
<div class="notify">
    <div class="child">
        12334        
    </div>
</div>
```

this jQuery script should do it..

```
var cw = $('.child').width();
$('.child').css({
    'height': cw + 'px',
    'line-height': cw + 'px'
});
```

Comment: Not, if you try, for example <div class="notify">
    <div class="child">
        12<br />
        12<br />
        12<br />
        12<br />
    </div>
</div>

Comment: Umair wrote `content inside is dynamic`. This means it can change in width or height. Why should always be width > height?

Comment: well, it might break but for one line of centered text it works fine!, unlike yours which leaves the text at the top so if the text is long then the text comes out of the circle, so tbh my solution is better (supposing 1 line of text)

Answer (score 0):

Forcing it's maximum height and weight by setting `max-width:XXpx; max-height:XXpx` will do the job.

Please note that you may need to use CSS3 `word-wrap: break-word;` to break the words. Cross-browser compatibility might be an issue.