# resize absolute div inside relative div with liquid css

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position, absolute

Ok...here is my problem:
I have a webpage with html & body set from css to:

```
body,html{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and also a webkit tag to disable the scrollbar:

```
/*Disable scrolling*/
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

inside of the body i use 3 divs to cover the entire available space in the page:
(i will not use the actual css code for the divs because it's unimportant for this matter and i will write only a basic code to get the ideea)
As i said, three relative divs to cover the available 100% height and width:

```
.div1{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}
.div2{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}
.div3{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}
```

Now here is my problem: 
  *** inside the middle div (div2) i have 4 concentric circles all of which are absolute divs wrote in css3. It is really important that these divs remain "absolute".

here is the css for them:

```
.size-large,
.size-normal,
.size-small,
.main-frame{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: transparent;
    border: 3px dotted #999;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

    .main-frame{
        width: 50%;
        padding-bottom: 50%;
        margin-top:-25%; /* push back half */
    }
    .size-large{
        width: 30%;
        padding-bottom: 30%;
        margin-top:-15%; /* push back half */
    }
    .size-normal {
        width: 20%;
        padding-bottom: 20%;
        margin-top:-10%; /* push back half */
    }
    .size-small {
        width: 10%;
        padding-bottom: 10%;
        margin-top:-5%; /* push back half */
    }
```

Problem is that those circles does not resize acording to the relative div of which they belong.
Their width/height given in percentages, is set acording to the body element.

I want my design to be liquid and to use only the available webpage without scrolling but also to resize all it's elements on any display.

FULL SCREEN RESULT: http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7mU/1/embedded/result/

CODE VIEW: http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7mU/1/

Comment: Do you have a demo jsFiddle or something to share? Or at least your HTML?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I'll make the demo now, give me 5 minutes please.

Comment: @ZachSaucier  This is the FULL SCREEN result: http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7mU/embedded/result/   and here is the code link: http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7mU/

Comment: @ZachSaucier Sorry, i had to update the links because i left some unwanted text in there. I wrote the links in the original post. I'll leave them in this comment too: http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7mU/1/embedded/result/ and  http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7mU/1/

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to ensure your concentric circles to stay within the blue div whilst maintaining a perfect round circle according to the percentage width you have set (i.e. .main-frame {width: 50%}, .size-large {width: 30%), .size-normal {width: 20%}, .size-small {width: 10%})

Your circles are indeed adjusting according to your blue div (based on width % not height %). So since your blue div has width=100%, the circles will adjust according to that only.

You will need to find a way of using BOTH height and width % so it maintains aspect ratio and central positioning.

I would recommend reading on this thread which provides possible solutions:
[HTML and CSS Fluid Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623975/html-and-css-fluid-circle)